# How can i get all audio parameters in python scipy?

Tags: python, audio, feature-detection

I have to use `scipy.io.wavfile` library to extract the audio parameters. i know i can use python `wave` to get all audio parameters. But how can i do it with `scipy.io.wavfile`

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
(sample_rate,signal) = wav.read("english.wav")
n_channels = signal.shape[1]
```

But how can i get other parameters.

```
frame_rate = ?
total_n_frames = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
frame_rate = sample_rate
total_n_frames = signal.shape[0]
```